# L'Hopital rule to show limit does not exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Determine whether the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{e^n}{n}}$$

diverges or converges.

The solution given goes as follow:

Note that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{e^n}{n}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{e^x}{x}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{e^x}{1}} = \infty$$

By the Divergence test, the series diverges.

Question: I thought the L'hopital rule cannot be used to show limit does not exist. But in the solution provided, it does so. May I know whether the solution is correct or not?

Comment: It's correct. The limit must exists, no matter if it is finite or not.

Comment: @Antioquia3943: you refer to correct solution or correct application of L'Hopital rule?

Comment: The solution is correct.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: You can use the L'hopital to show that $a_n$ diverges which implies $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: De l'Hopital rule is useless here. $\frac{e^n}{n}$ is blatantly unbounded as $n\to +\infty$, hence the series is divergent.

Comment: For instance: $$\frac{e^n}{n}\geq \frac{1+n+\frac{n^2}{2}}{n} \geq \frac{n}{2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ratio test $$a_n=\frac{e^n}{n}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{e n}{n+1}\sim e-\frac e n$$ So, divergence and not much to do with L'Hôpital's rule which, I agree, shows that $a_n\to \infty$ from which you could also conclude.